# Browser rendering faux bold - not font face bold

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I have a regular and bold version of a font face implemented like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventor';
  src: url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.svg#TeXGyreAdventorRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal; }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventor';
  src: url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.svg#TeXGyreAdventorbold') format('svg');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal; }

body { font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventor'; }
```

Now I would expect anything told to be bold in the CSS to use the bold version of the font and everything else to use the regular version. Alas this doesn't work. The browser uses the regular version for everything and implements it's own faux style.

If on the other hand I implement the font face like this:

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventor';
      src: url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.eot');
      src: url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-regular-webfont.svg#TeXGyreAdventorRegular') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }

    @font-face {
      font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventorBold';
      src: url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.eot');
      src: url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
      url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
      url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/texgyreadventor-bold-webfont.svg#TeXGyreAdventorbold') format('svg');
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }

body { font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventor'; }

b,strong { 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'TeXGyreAdventorBold'; }
```

Then it works! What gives? I thought the first method is suppose to work. Am I doing something wrong? Is there no way for the browser to understand what is bold and apply the correct version of the font? I don't want to have to declare a new font family for any bit of CSS I want to make bold!

Comment: Sometimes it depends on the browser...It also depends on your OS, no web font is going to look perfect because of these variables of the font rendering capabilities of your browser and OS.

Comment: @brandonjordan You misunderstood me. I'm not talking about the way the browser is rendering the font, I'm saying that method 1 doesn't use the bold font at all and method 2 does.

Comment: The first version is correct. You are doing something wrong. To get more specific information, please provide more information, such as a testable document (in a manner that gives access to the actual font files) and identify the browser(s) tested.